# Grouping according to the number of values present in columns in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, grouping

I have a table like:

```
entry cs1 cs2 cs3 cs4 cs5
12    2   3   4   2   
13    1   3   4   1
14    4   5   6   2    2
15    2   4   2        4   
16    2   3   1   2    4
17    5   6   3   2    1
18        2   3   5    1
```

I am using crystal reports linked with Excel file. How can I output with grouping the rows with specific column values defined like:

```
entry cs1 cs2 cs3 cs4
12    2   3   4   2   
13    1   3   4   1
entry cs1 cs2 cs3 cs4 cs5
14    4   5   6   2    2
entry cs1 cs2 cs3 cs5
15    2   4   2   4   
entry cs1 cs2 cs3 cs4 cs5
16    2   3   1   2    4
17    5   6   3   2    1
entry cs2 cs3 cs4 cs5
18    2   3   5    1
```

Comment: What is the criteria that 12 and 13 should come in one group

Comment: They contain same set of column values i.e. both do not have any value in CS5 column.

Comment: @NitikaChowdhary Why aren't entries 14, 15, and 16 grouped then? They have all 5 values.